# Convert Matricies in Armadillo from Sparse to Dense (spmat to mat)

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix, armadillo

I'm using the Armadillo C++ linear algebra library, and I'm trying to figure out how to convert an `sp_mat` sparse matrix object to a standard `mat` dense matrix.

Looking at the [internal code doc](http://arma.sourceforge.net/internal_docs_4300/), `sp_mat` and `mat` don't share a common parent class, which leads me to believe there isn't a way to cast an `sp_mat` as a `mat`. By the way, `conv_to<mat>::from(sp_mat x)` doesn't work.

Perhaps there's a tricky way to do this using one of the advanced `mat` constructors? For example, somehow create a mat of zeros and pass the locations and values of non-zero elements in the `sp_mat`.

Does anyone know of an efficient method to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Casting works perfectly fine:

```
sp_mat X(2,2);

mat Y(X);

Y.print("Y:");
```

Comment: Wow. I can't believe I missed that. Thanks very much! Maybe I'm missing something, but I didn't see sp_mat as an input to a mat constructor in the api doc. http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Mat